# PHP Session is treating as different domain, after adding a 'www.' infront of webpage

Tags: php, session

if i am setting a session in http://example.com/path/file1.php

then can't getting it in http://www.example.com/path/file2.php
but getting the value in http://example.com/path/file2.php

- the "www." is creating the issue.

Is that a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, thats intended behaviour.

"" is treated as another subdomain than "www" (or other ones, if you have more subdomains), and so it's saved in a different cookie (per default, a cookies validity is per domain).

to avoid this, you could simply redirect users that enter from http://example.com/path/file1.php (or anything else with "example.com") to http://www.example.com/path/file1.php (or anything else with "www.example.com")

Comment: Ahh! No redirect it the other way. www. is so old fashioned and pointless. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can share the session cookie across all subdomains if you call [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session-set-cookie-params) with a value of ".example.com" (notice the leading dot) in the domain parameter,

Answer (score 1):

To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com (including example.com itself) then you'd set the domain parameter in setcookie() method to '.example.com'

[src [here]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)